# Filling up a Form to update data table

Tags: ms-access

I have to create a user-friendly form that allows employees to add details regarding a new shop branch to a data table, also in Access. Using only Microsoft Access, a user has to fill up a form with the relevant details so that a new entry will be appended to a data table.

E.g. A new shop branch will have the fields ShopID, ShopName, and PersonInCharge. Upon filling up a form with these 3 details, a user will click a button "Submit". Doing so will create a new entry in a data table.

I have tried linking the button to run a query that updates the data table but no new entries are created. I have also tried using the "Append" function as part of Query Design, but running it would append "0" rows.

Unfortunately I can't take any screenshots since I'm doing this in a company as part of my internship. This is my first time using Microsoft Access. Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you just want to make a simple form that simply add a record into your table right?

why don't you create a desired table first then create wizard form on it. It will automatically generate a form as needed then you can add a button using wizard choose categories -> record operations -> add new record.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow thanks for the prompt reply! I tried this out, however, if I have existing records in the data table, an entry would be overridden. Is there anyway I can add on a record to the same data table or another data table to prevent the accidental editing of existing records?

Comment: I believe 'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec' creates a new instance for you.